# How is keyed state managed for KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using `BroadcastState` to perform streaming computation in Flink. I have defined a class extending `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` for my job. Say I have a stream A which is keyed by `(user_id, location)`, and a stream B, which is broadcasted to all executors to process elements in A using my defined class. I understand I can registered a timer in `processBroadcastElement` or `processElement` in this class so that when it times out, I can delete the associated state for a specific key group by calling `state.clear()`. I wonder after that, does this key group still exist?

For example, in stream A, a new message comes with `(user_id=1, location='usa')` and we have such key group and its associated states generated. After that if another message with `(user_id=1, location='usa')` comes, it will trigger `processElement()` and emit result.

Say after 24 hours, I'm no longer interested with this key group `(user_id=1, location='usa')`, I can register a timer to clear the associated state, but I have no control of this key group. As a result, after 24 hours, when another message with `(user_id=1, location='usa')` comes, since this key group still exists, `processElement()` will still be invoked. As the job runs, although their associated states will be cleared after 24 hours, will key groups accumulate or that should not be a concern for memory usage?

Relevant blogs: https://www.da-platform.com/blog/a-practical-guide-to-broadcast-state-in-apache-flink

Answer (score 1):

Flink's keyed state is organized as a distributed (or sharded) key-value store, where the keys can be simple things, like integers and strings, or composites, like (user_id=1, location='usa'). *Key groups* are something different than *composite keys*. A key group is a runtime construct that was introduced in Flink 1.2 (see [FLINK-3755](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3755)) to permit efficient rescaling of key-value state. A key group is a subset of the key space, and is checkpointed as an independent unit. At runtime, all of the keys in the same key group are partitioned together in job graph -- each subtask has the key-value state for one or more complete key groups. This [design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1OS1z3xEBOrYD4wSu-LuBCyPUWyFd9l3T9WyssQ63w/edit#heading=h.2suhu1fjxmp4) gives more details. As a user working with the DataStream API, key groups are an implementation detail, and not something you work with directly.

As for timers in a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`, they can be registered in the `processElement` or `onTimer` method, but not in the `processBroadcastElement` method. This is because timers are always associated with a key, and there is no key associated with a broadcast element. You can, however, manipulate any or all of the keyed state during your `processBroadcastElement` method by using the `applyToKeyedState` method on the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction.Context` object. See the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html#broadcastprocessfunction-and-keyedbroadcastprocessfunction) for more details.

Once you call state.clear(), the state entry for that key is deleted. New stream events for that key may, of course, arrive after the state has been cleared, and you are able to once again store value state for that key, if you wish. In order to avoid unbounded memory usage due to keeping state for no-longer-relevant keys, you do need to be careful. You might want some logic like this to expire the state 24 hours after each time it is created:

```
processElement:
  if state.value() is null, register timer
  state.update(...)

onTimer:
  state.clear()
```

Or you might need more complex logic that extends the lifetime of the state whenever it is updated or accessed.

Another option would be to use the [state time-to-live](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) feature.

Update:

Whenever you are in a `processElement` or `onTimer` method of any of the ProcessFunction types, there is a specific key implicitly in context, and anything done to keyed state (such as `.update()` or `.clear()`) will only affect the state for that one key.

Broadcast state works differently. Broadcast state is always MapState, and is replicated into all of the parallel subtasks. Broadcast state is keyless -- if you read broadcast state during the `processElement` method you will see the same value for the broadcast state regardless of what key is in context during that call.

Only in the `processBroadcastElement` method of a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` can you modify (or clear) broadcast state, and it's important that whatever modifications (or deletions) occur be done in the same way in all of the parallel instances. This is designed this way so as to guarantee that every parallel instance will have the same contents in broadcast state. Ignoring this rule will lead to inconsistencies in the state, which can be very difficult to debug. See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html#important-considerations) for more info.

So yes, if you call .clear() on the broadcast state, then all of the broadcast state for all keys will be removed. Or you might remove a specific item from the broadcast state (remember, broadcast state is MapState), in which case that specific item will be removed for all keys.

There are several examples of working with broadcast state in the Flink training site. See

- https://training.da-platform.com/exercises/ongoingRides.html
- https://training.da-platform.com/exercises/nearestTaxi.html
- https://training.da-platform.com/exercises/taxiQuery.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer David! Yes I think I confused `composite key` with `key group`. Currently I'm registering a timer in `processElement` and calling `clear` whenever the timer fires. One thing I'd like to know is when I call `state.clear()`, is only the value associated with `(user_id=1, location='usa')` removed or both of them are removed? If in `onTimer` I call `ctx.getBroadcastState.clear()`, will that clear the broadcasted state for other keys?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "or both of them are removed", but I've expanded my answer to hopefully clarify things.